# Hosting web application on Google App Engine without installing Google SDK

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is is necessary to make changes to my Java project with respect to Google SDK in order to host my app on Google app engine.

Google has a whole different set of codes for different things and different jars that we got to include.

Can't I just export a war of my current java web application as war and host it on Google app engine?